# Unity Cardboard view tracking

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm looking to track how long a person looks at an object in Unity when using Google Cardboard (building for iOS).

I'm not sure how to go about this. Would it be the same as mouse tracking?

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On each update, use a raycast from the position of the camera to determine what (if any) object is directly in front of the camera. Whenever this object changes, calculate the time difference.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have already setup GvrReticlePointer and GvrViewerMain prefabs into your scene-

1. Create a script and add it to the GameObject from the inspector window.

   ```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
   public class TimeCounter: MonoBehaviour 
   {
       public float timer;
       void Update () 
       {
       timer += Time.deltaTime;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Hit play and gaze towards the game object. You would find the Timer value in the inspector getting changed. You could also customize the above script and modify to your need.